# ignore space in column value while loading data using sql loader by oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am trying to load data using oracle sql loader and using space as separator of columns but I am facing problem that one of the columns value including space, I need your support to avoid considering this space as column separator.

I tried to use regexp_replace and replace functions

```
DSTCOUNTRY " REGEXP_REPLACE(:DSTCOUNTRY,'dstcountry=','')",
```

the column value is: `dstcountry="United States"`

and the expecting value to be stored in the table is:
`United States`

The sql loader command is:
load data
 infile 'in'
append
 into table test_table
          fields terminated by " " optionally enclosed by '"'
      TRAILING NULLCOLS
DSTCOUNTRY " REPLACE(:DSTCOUNTRY,'dstcountry=','')",

I am using oracle 10G and 12C.

Comment: Can you please share the SQL loader command or parameter file which you have used to load the data? - Edit the question and add the details.

Comment: You may need to use the Oracle DataPump utility which has more flexibility on input data.  Can you also edit your question and add a tag for your Oracle version, such as `Oracle12c`

Answer (score 1):

According to what you posted so far, it is `optionally enclosed` you're looking for. Here's an example.

Test table:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, dstcountry varchar2(20));

Table created.
```

Control file (contains sample data as well):

```
load data 
infile *
replace
into table test
fields terminated by " " 
optionally enclosed by '"'
trailing nullcols
(
id,
dstcountry)

begindata
123 "Croatia"
125 "United States"
```

Loading session and result:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger control=test08.ctl log=test08.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Pon Srp 22 17:59:23 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 1
Commit point reached - logical record count 2

SQL> select * from test;

        ID DSTCOUNTRY
---------- --------------------
       123 Croatia
       125 United States

SQL>
```

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your answer but according to this the loader will consider dstcountry="United States" 2 columns since there is space between United and States?

Comment: You're welcome. Didn't you see the example? Was "United States" loaded into two columns? No, it was not.

Comment: but I have the data as the following: dstcountry="United States" so I have to use the function as the following: DSTCOUNTRY " REGEXP_REPLACE(:DSTCOUNTRY,'dstcountry=','')",

Comment: I am using the function REGEXP_REPLACE to remove the part dstcountry= from the data.

Comment: Why would you involve regular expressions? Ordinary `replace` will do the job.

Comment: I have used REPLACE as the following: DSTCOUNTRY " REPLACE(:DSTCOUNTRY,'dstcountry=','')", but still the loader considering dstcountry="United States" as 2 columns?

Comment: I am using this loader: 
 load data
 infile 'in'
append
 into table test_table
          fields terminated by " " optionally enclosed by '"'
   TRAILING NULLCOLS

Comment: Aha. Only the country name is enclosed into double quotes (e.g. `dstcountry="United States"`), not the whole column value (e.g. `"dstcountry=United States"`). Replace removes `dstcountry=`, but SQL Loader doesn't take the remaining string as the "new" input, but uses the space as a field terminator and loads only the first "word" - `United`. I'm not sure you can fix that in SQL Loader. Consider pre-processing the file; either by search/replace function, or see whether you can get the file without it.

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts, appreciated.